# Stock tracking in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, stock

How do we control the stock in Store?

I enter the stock level into field Limit Stock. The store nows now that there is some stock.

[image]
What is the meaning of the check box?

And will Store change the number when 1 item is ordered? It does not in our case. Is this normal that we need to change the number in the entry by hand?

I might have overseen something in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit stock button will tell store that it can only sell so much of that particular sku. Once that sku is down to 0 the item will be out of stock and can no longer be purchased. If you get more of that item in you will need to edit the entry with the updated quantity.

If I remember correctly you will only see the stock change if you have check the limit stock box.